# Как избежать перечисления исключений?

Tags: c#, исключения

Некий код выбрасывает несколько видов исключений, обработка которых одинакова. Например:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (InvalidOperationException e)
{
    // ...
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Код, выполняемый в блоках catch идентичен. Я поместил его в функцию onException(). Но, тем не менее, все равно ветвей кода довольно много.

Есть ли способ сделать фильтр по исключениям иначе - более кратко?

Comment: не?
 
   catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ...
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример [решения аналогичного вопроса на stackowerflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136092/897090)

```
catch (Exception ex)            
{                
    if (ex is InvalidOperationException || ex is ArgumentException)
    {
        onException();
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну а throw зачем?

Comment: Чтобы дальнейшие обработчики могли поймать.

Comment: Всё правильно, одно смущает, скобки не нужны ещё?

    (ex is InvalidOperationException || ex is ArgumentException)

Comment: @Jofsey, вопрос о том, чтобы уменьшить кол-во обработчиков, но нет же, вы пробрасываете исключение дальше

Comment: вопрос о том, чтобы не дублировать код в каждой catch секцие, если я правильно понял.

Comment: @AlexAndR пририоритет у оператора `is` выше, чем у оператора `||`, если вы об этом.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Все типы эксепций унаследованы от одного, можно обрабатывать его.
Если не хотите мешать исключения которые вы предусмотрели от других, сделайте для InvalidOperationException  и ArgumentException общего предка и обрабатывайте его (последнее только если это ваши собственные исключения).